# Is it possible to compute Edge Betweenness of a specific edge in graph using NetworkX in python?

Tags: python, networkx

I am able to calculate edge betweenness of all edges in a graph using networkX using the code `nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(Graph)`. But my goal is not to calculate this measure for all of the edges in graph due to the size of the graph. Is there any efficient way just to calculate edge betweenness for a specific edge??